# Delphi - C++ interoperability concerning containers

Tags: c++, delphi, containers

I have a C/C++ .dll containing core functionality of my program, and a  Delphi project for the graphical user interface.
Is there any way I can export something like a std::vector or std::map to Delphi and use it in C++?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ classes can only be directly consumed by C++ code. Similarly, Delphi classes can only be directly consumed by Delphi code.

An exception to these rules is that Embarcadero's compilers have interop support and it is possible to consume some Delphi classes from C++ code, so long as the C++ code is compiled using an Embarcadero compiler.

Assuming that you are not using an Embarcadero C++ compiler you will need to wrap any classes that you wish to export in an interop friendly manner. The obvious choice for this is COM which was designed to solve this very problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will investigate on COM

Comment: I'd like to plug my article about this: [Using C++ objects in Delphi](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html). It describes a way using COM and a way using flat functions.